# How can I make this form break/go to another row in a certain place for phones in twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that looks nice on a full screen but doesn't fit on phones. I used a bit of a hack to break the form on a phone but it doesn't center nicely and I would like to know what the best practice bootstrap method is for having this display nicely on a phone. I would like it to break in the same place, but being centered properly on a phone. How can I do this? Is there a bootstrap way to tell it where to break? Or do I need to use sub rows (which seems hard).

http://www.bootply.com/123978 (edit: fixed link)
You have to click on the mobile button to see what it looks like in bootply.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="cas_app">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Calculator
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form id = "cas_form" method="GET" action="Servlet">
                        <div class ="input-group date" id = "cas_input_row">
                            <input id = "cas_datepicker" type = "text" class="form-control" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" />
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="cas_datebutton">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </button>
                            <div id = "cas_radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="operation" value="plus">plus<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="operation" value="minus">minus
                            </div>
                            <p class="visible-xs"><br><br></p>
                            <input name = "daystoaddorsubtract" type = "number" class="form-control" placeholder="#" id = "cas_text2"/>
                            <div id = "cas_radios">
                                <input type="radio" name="cal_or_work" value="calendar">calendar days<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="cal_or_work" value="work">work days
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "row" id = "cas_buttons">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Calculate Dates!</button> 
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Reset</button>
                        </div>

                        <input id="month" name="month" value="" type="hidden"/>
                        <input id="day" name="day" value="" type="hidden"/>
                        <input id="year" name="year" value="" type="hidden"/>
                        <input id="formID" name="formID" value="ca_add_subtract" type="hidden"/>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

>

CSS:

```
#cas_form {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;

}

#cas_input_row {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 450px;
}

#cas_datepicker {
    width: 110px;
    float: left;

}

#cas_datebutton {
    float: left;
}

#cas_radios {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: left;
}

#cas_text2 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    float: left;

}

#cas_buttons {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#cas_results {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#cas_startOver {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
#cas_form {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;

}

#cas_input_row {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 450px;
}

#cas_datepicker {
    width: 110px;
    float: left;

}

#cas_datebutton {
    float: left;
}

#cas_radios {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: left;
}

#cas_text2 {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 70px;
    float: left;

}

#cas_buttons {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#cas_results {
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#cas_startOver {
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your code and this is what is making it look weird

```
<p class="visible-xs"><br><br></p>
```

You need to add classes for every viewport inside for it to break nicely!

```
col-md-# col-xs-#
```

Comment: Thanks. When I add xs columns I have an issue where it breaks it even on large screens. Why doesn't the large screen ignore the xs columns? http://www.bootply.com/123981#

Comment: I was testing the same to no avail! But you need to try out that and probably a bit of offsetting

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this template:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting